# bash terminal command to be repeated after it exited

Tags: terminal, android, vlc-media-player

this command on android terminal (and adb shell)

```
do am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d rtsp://theurl
```

launches VLC and automatically starts streaming.

how do i make it automatically running that command again after VLC exits?

I have tried this

```
while :; do am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d rtsp://theurl; command; done
```

but it keeps repeating the command even when VLC still running.

Comment: The simple answer is you can't. `am start` returns immediately and there is no way to make it wait.

Comment: i wonder, can it be added with a command to watch for vlc process? so after the process exit, repeat the 1st command.

Comment: I assume you want to make sure the display always shows a certain video. Your first problem is that the vlc process will remain active even if it is sent to background. The second problem is that to my knowledge there is no way to wait for an app. Therefore the best chance you have is to check the video length and add a sleep command in your bash loop of the same duration.

Comment: i just checked, the VLC process did not exits after the stream stopped. You are right. I'll post a new question with better method: My thinking is that periodically (ever 1 sec?) check whether VLC is in foreground, and  automatically re-run the script to launch vlc to stream the video again if vlc is no longer not in foreground. So in case a stream got interrupted, it automatically relaunch vlc and starts streaming again.

Comment: Or use a video playing app that supports a kiosk mode. So you don't have to manage it from outside.

Comment: i managed to found the solution. i don't think its a good code, but it works https://superuser.com/questions/1686852/bash-terminal-command-to-be-repeated-after-an-activity-no-longer-foreground/1686870#1686870  as for other app, i cant find it. thus my adventure to the code.