# Bash terminal command to be repeated after an activity no longer foreground

Tags: bash, terminal, android, vlc-media-player, streaming

so the context:

I want to make a bash terminal command that will launch VLC to stream a video, and then when VLC is no longer in the foreground (VLC automatically goes to the background when the stream is interrupted too long), it will repeat the command to launch VLC to stream again.

I got the working separate command codes, but I don't have any idea how to make these work into one command that keeps repeating.

1. To launch VLC and starts streaming:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d rtsp://theurl
```

This will launch/bring to the foreground the default app for RTSP (in this case, VLC) and starts streaming.

2. To check whether VLC is still in the foreground or not

```
dumpsys activity activities | sed -e '/mResumedActivity/!d' -e '/vlc/!d'
```

This will return something like this when VLC is in the foreground.

```
 mResumedActivity: ActivityRecord{b43545d u0 org.videolan.vlc/.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity t11827}
```

and will return nothing in the terminal if VLC is not in the foreground.

---

so maybe the code will be doing something like this?

every 1 second, check for VLC is in the foreground or not (using code number 2). If VLC is not in the foreground, launch vlc with the streaming URL (using code number 1). if vlc is in the foreground, keep checking.

Comment: using this errorenous command `until dumpsys activity activities | sed -e '/mResumedActivity/!d' -e '/vlc/!q100'; do sleep 1 | echo "no stream..."; done` it keeps printing "no stream" while vlc is not in the foreground (so far so good). but it instantly stops when vlc is in the foreground (i need it to loop back to command number 2). So when i replaced the echo command to the launch vlc command, it works only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this loop:

```
while true; do
   foreground="$(dumpsys activity activities | sed -e '/mResumedActivity/!d' -e '/vlc/!d')"
   if [[ "$foreground" == "" ]]; then
       am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d rtsp://theurl
   fi
   sleep 1
done
```

It just checks if the `am` command returns nothing and if it does, it starts vlc.

Comment: thank you, if you dont mind, can it be made into 1 line? so i can launch it without uploading an .sh file first. or I'm misunderstanding and it can be directly launched from terminal without uploading an .sh file first?

Comment: how do i mark you as answer? your code is right! i transformed it into one line like this `while true; do   foreground="$(dumpsys activity activities | sed -e '/mResumedActivity/!d' -e '/vlc/!d')";   if [[ "$foreground" == "" ]]; then       am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d rtsp://xxxx;   fi;   sleep 1; done` and it works! thanks a bunch!

Comment: @orangpelupa glad it worked out for you :)

Answer (score 0):

i think this is a bad command, as it deliberately makes sed errors, but it works

```
watch -n1 'dumpsys activity activities | sed -e '/mResumedActivity/!d' -e '/vlc/!q100' || am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d rtsp://address;'
```

so every time the stream is interrupted, it automatically re-launch vlc and reconnect to the stream again.